# Can't set up a lightning component tab for one of my components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, tab

My Salesforce1 lightning app has 2 main pages: an app landing page and an admin page (there are also several supporting pages).

I can successfully deploy all objects and code from my personal developer sandbox to the company org developer sandbox, and I am also able to assign a tab to the admin page, but the dropdown for assigning lightning components to tabs does not contain my app's landing page component.  It does show my other components as well, just not the one for the main landing page.  This is not happening in my personal developer sandbox - that works perfectly.

I have tried deleting the component bundle and re-deploying as well as adding it back manually, and I have also tried deleting many other component bundles and adding only that one back, but nothing works.

I will also mention the obvious:

- I did set up a MyDomain and have logged out and back in several times
- I do have implements="force:appHostable" set in the component in
  question

Comment: **Update:** I was able to deploy the tab using force.com IDE, however when I tried to edit it, it wouldn't let me save. This time it gave an error message: _"You can only create lightning tabs for AuraDefinitionBundles containing a component that implements force:appHostable and has no required attributes without a default value. (Related field: Content)"_ **Note: both of those conditions have been met...**

Comment: I also tried creating an entirely new page using the content from the existing page and I still couldn't create a tab for it.